# How do I register an aws ec2 instance into an ecs cluster (not using the aws console)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am unable to register previously created ec2 instances into a cluster using the register_container_instance from the python boto3 library:

```
response = client.register_container_instance(
    cluster=cluster_name,
    instanceIdentityDocument='inst_id_doc.txt',
    instanceIdentityDocumentSignature='inst_id_sign.txt' 
)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
`traceback(most recent call last)import boto3
File "whetstone_2.py", line 79 in <module>
instanceIdentityDocumentSignature='inst_id_sign.txt'
File "C:\Users\ishanigh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py",line 251, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name,kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ishanigh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py",line 251, in _api_call
    raise ClientError(parsed_response,operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.clientError: An error occurred (ServerException)
```

when calling the RegisterContainerInstance operation (reached max retries: 4):Service Unavailable.Please try again later.`
I got the instance_id_doc.txt and inst_id_sign.txt from the instances. And the process of registering the container instances have to be automated.
How should this be done?